# Is it possible to squeeze and stretch water with large enough forces?

Tags: thermodynamics, elasticity

I know that water isn't easily compressed, but let's consider a box completely full of water and the walls of the boxes made from water. Also imagine one pump at each side of the box and they are all pushing in unison with same pressures at all times, with starting pressure 1 atm. We keep the temperature of water constant at all times and above the triple point.

Now we start increasing the pressure of the pumps all to the point where water turns into ice. We continue increasing the pressure, until we break the ice. Is such process possible?

Also what about the opposite, where in the same circumstances we gradually decrease the pressure of the pumps. Would we succeed in stretching the water? What would happen as we decrease the pressure further? I've read that it would kind of break apart (while still being liquid). Obviously from studying the phase diagram, at some point it would turn to vapor at which point we're not anymore interested in what happens, since I'm thinking that nothing noteworthy would indeed happen.

Is my reasoning correct for these cases?

Comment: **Would we succeed in stretching the water,..... I've read that it would kind of break apart** You would need to expand on that in a physical sense. They are very vague sentences, imo. Do mean produce $H_2$ and $O_2$?

Comment: No, stretching as in reducing the density of the water by meas of increasing its volume. By "break apart" (I'm just citing what I've read),  I mean divide in droplets.

Comment: I am not sure that that makes sense physically, the density of a droplet of water is the same as density of a litre of water, all other things being equal. (Such as temperature, but changes in pressure, which you are up to, I don't know,  TBH)

Comment: Well I think that it might make sense if we look at it from a standpoint that the intermolecular forces couldn't keep up with the forces that are expanding the water thus breaking them apart in droplets of the same density of course. Something like crushing some solid until it is crushed into pieces.

Comment: Source of the breaking in droplets thing: http://cps-www.bu.edu/Wasser/robert/work/node15.html

Comment: **Now we start increasing the pressure of the pumps all to the point where water turns into ice. We continue increasing the pressure, until we break the ice. Is such process possible?**  What does the phase diagram for water tell you?

Comment: Well the phase diagram tells me that water will eventually turn into ice, and then the Young's modulus graph tells me that the ice will eventually break.